# Scala's collect inefficient in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am currently starting to learn to use spark with Scala. The problem I am working on needs me to read a file, split each line on a certain character, then filtering the lines where one of the columns matches a predicate and finally remove a column. So the basic, naive implementation is a map, then a filter then another map.

This meant going through the collection 3 times and that seemed quite unreasonable to me. So I tried replacing them by one collect (the collect that takes a partial function as an argument). And much to my surprise, this made it run much slower. I tried locally on regular Scala collections; as expected, the latter way of doing is much faster.

So why is that ? My idea is that the map and filter and map are not applied sequentially, but rather mixed into one operation; in other words, when an action forces evaluation every element of the list will be checked and the pending operations will be executed. Is that right ? But even so, why do the collect perform so badly ?

EDIT: a code example to show what I want to do:

The naive way:

```
sc.textFile(...).map(l => {
  val s = l.split(" ") 
  (s(0), s(1))
}).filter(_._2.contains("hello")).map(_._1)
```

The collect way:

```
sc.textFile(...).collect {
  case s if(s.split(" ")(0).contains("hello")) => s(0)
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what exactly did you save during the "non-naive" way. Which resource do you believe will be used less in the second approach?

You are collecting your RDD, which forces the movement of the entire data to a single machine, which usually comes with either a performance penalty or OOM exceptions.

Comment: Well I don't think I do. Collect, with a partial function as an argument, "returns an RDD that contains all matching values by applying f." So from what I understand it should behave like map except that it's a partial function. So even if it's not faster it shouldn't be much slower.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, your examples do different things. "Naive way" returns first parts of the split strings, while "collect way" returns first chars of the input strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer lies in the implementation of `collect`:

```
/**
 * Return an RDD that contains all matching values by applying `f`.
 */
def collect[U: ClassTag](f: PartialFunction[T, U]): RDD[U] = withScope {
  val cleanF = sc.clean(f)
  filter(cleanF.isDefinedAt).map(cleanF)
}
```

As you can see, it's the same sequence of `filter`->`map`, but less efficient in your case.

In scala both `isDefinedAt` and `apply` methods of `PartialFunction` evaluate `if` part.

So, in your "collect" example `split` will be performed twice for each input element.

Comment: And here I was, thinking collect was something different from map and filter. Thank you very much for your answer good sir.